# Could we use form authentication mode in asp.net web api

Tags: asp.net, forms, authentication, asp.net-web-api, configuration-files

I would like to secure my asp.net web api application, so instead of using basic authentication I set the authentication mode in the web.config file to "forms", is this method wrong or not secure.

Comment: I consume this api from another web site, and I would like to know is this a right method?

Comment: welcome to SO! Provide some code for your question: what you tried, etc See also  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Forms authentication is a good option. You need to create tables for that, mainly Users table to store username and passwords of the users. If you have different roles for the users then add Roles table and keep role_id in users table.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I consume the api from an html page through ajax, is that suitable?

Comment: Yes, all the authentication related code will be in api. Using html and ajax, you can pass the credentials to the api.